# How do I trust a UNC path?

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint, microsoft-office-2016, trust

I have a shortcut on my desktop to a document:

`"\\mycompany.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\MTCTeamSite\tech\Shared Documents\Team Documents\spreadsheet.xlsm"`

Every time I open it in Excel I have to click "Enable Editing" and then "Edit Document"

[image]
[image]

According to the documentation as I understand it, once I do this it should be added to my trusted documents.  It doesn't seem to matter.

In the office Trust Center I have checked `Allow Trusted locations on my network (not recommended)` and I have added `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com` to the trusted locations list.

I cannot add a UNC path (\\) and a windows shortcut cannot point to a web link (http).

I have also "Cleared" all trusted documents and tried again.  I do have "Allow documents on a network to be trusted" checked as well.

**How can I trust this document so that it no longer opens read-only and in protected view?**

Answer (score -1):

You should just disable Protected view altogether. It's not a particularly helpful feature.

Click file, then options. On the left side of the options window, click trust center. Open the trust center settings, then click the Protected View tab on the left and uncheck the boxes there.

Comment: I'm unsure whether I should be answering How to trust a UNC path, or how to trust the document so that it no longer opens read-only and in protected view? I don't believe there's a suitable answer for either. That's why I suggested turning off protected view.